# Reading SQL query using Polars and cx_Oracle gives error

Tags: python, cx-oracle, python-polars

I'm trying to read a SQL-query using the python library Polars. Firstly, I establish a connection using the cx_Oracle library as follows:

```
import polars as ps
import cx_Oracle as oracle

user = XXX
host = XXX
port = XXX
service_name = XXX
password = XXX
dsnStr = oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name)
gds_con = oracle.connect(user, password, dsnStr)

query = XXX
```

Then, I want to make use of Polars:

```
result = ps.read_database(query, gds_con)
```

But the latter results in the following error:

```
'cx_Oracle.Connection' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Shouldn't you try `ps.from_arrow(...)`? Also what I did in a similar situation was reading it with pandas then converting to polars and deleting the pandas object.

Comment: The reason I want to directly read it to a polars dataframe is because it's much faster

Comment: [`.read_database` uses connectorx.](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/io/database/) - https://sfu-db.github.io/connector-x/databases/oracle.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

polars uses [connectorx](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x) to make database connections. It doesn't use a cx_Oracle connection object as you're trying to feed it. It uses a connection string. From [here](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/discussions/130) I found this example format of the connection string:

```
cstr = f"oracle://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}"
```

or maybe

```
cstr = f"oracle://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{service_name}"
```

Then you can do

```
import polars as pl
result = pl.read_database(query, cstr)
```